# workaround sql govenor limits

Tags: apex, trigger, soql, governorlimits, limits

I am building this program that will generate numbers in fields based off of other records in that object.  As such, queries will be needed. I have the program to the point where it will update when the record is touched and it works great.
    My problem is that the only way I could figure out how to make it work is by putting the queries in a loop which will flag governor limits.
    My question is, based off the code I've given, can anybody figure out a way to generate the queries outside of the loop?
Also any ideas about using formulas that could achieve the same thing in the object itself would be great as well
**Test Class**

```
@isTest
public class dependentSearchTest {

    testmethod static void verifyChange()
    {
        //need to create an instance of all user accounts 
        Plan__c plan = new Plan__c(Name = 'testplan',Plan_Rate__c = 1.5, Base_Rate__c = 1.5, Market_Year__c = '2016');

        Account tpa = new Account(Name = 'tpa',RecordTypeId ='012i0000000rx9SAAQ');
        insert tpa;

        //Age_Rate__c age = new Age_Rate__c(Name = '45',Age_Multiplier__c = 1.111);
        //insert age;   


        Account memberPerspective = new Account(Name = 'Member Perspective',
                                                Raitings_Region__c = '4',
                                                Group_TPA__c=tpa.id,
                                                RecordTypeId='012i0000000rqxg');
        insert memberPerspective;

         Member_Group__c memberGroup = new Member_Group__c(Name = 'membergroup',Account__c = memberPerspective.id,RecordTypeId='012i0000000rl51');
        insert memberGroup;

        Contact contact = new Contact (/*Account = memberPerspective.id,*/LastName='scott',/*Age_Rate2__c=age.id,Birthdate= '2/15/2000' ,*/RecordTypeId='012i0000001MOfb');
        insert contact;
        string role;
        Subscriber__c[] subsc = new list<Subscriber__c>();
        for (integer j=0;j<402;j++){
       for (Integer i=1;i<10;i++) {
           if (i==1)
           {role = 'Subscriber';}
           else{role = 'dependent';}
           Subscriber__c sub = new Subscriber__c(Name = j+'1456000'+i,
                                               Subscriber_ID__c = j+'14560',
                                               Subscriber_Role__c = role,
                                               Count__c = i,
                                               Subscriber_Plan__c = plan.id,
                                               Subscriber_Name__c = contact.id,
                                               Member_Group__c = memberGroup.id,
                                               Account__c=memberPerspective.id//,
                                               //Rating_Region__c = memberPerspective.Raitings_Region__c

                                             );subsc.add(sub);

       }}
        insert subsc;
        Test.startTest();
        test.stopTest();
    }
}
```

**Apex Class**

```
public class dependentSearchClass 
{
    public static void dependentSearch(Subscriber__c[] subs)
    {
    final Decimal fallbackRate = 3.000;
    final Decimal smokerFallbackRate = 1.00;
    final map<String, Decimal> ageToRate = new map<String, Decimal>
    {
        '0'=>.635,'1'=>.635,'2'=>.635,'3'=>.635,'4'=>.635,'5'=>.635,'6'=>.635,'7'=>.635,'8'=>.635,
        '9'=>.635,'10'=>.635,'11'=>.635,'12'=>.635,'13'=>.635,'14'=>.635,'15'=>.635,'16'=>.635,'17'=>.635,
        '18'=>.635,'19'=>.635,'20'=>.635,'21'=>1.000,'22'=>1.000,'23'=>1.000,'24'=>1.000,'25'=>1.004,
        '26'=>1.024,'27'=>1.048,'28'=>1.087,'29'=>1.119,'30'=>1.135,'31'=>1.159,'32'=>1.183,'33'=>1.198,
        '34'=>1.214,'35'=>1.222,'36'=>1.23,'37'=>1.238,'38'=>1.246,'39'=>1.262,'40'=>1.278,'41'=>1.302,'42'=>1.325,
        '43'=>1.357,'44'=>1.397,'45'=>1.444,'46'=>1.5,'47'=>1.563,'48'=>1.635,'49'=>1.706,'50'=>1.786,'51'=>1.865,
        '52'=>1.952,'53'=>2.02,'54'=>2.135,'55'=>2.23,'56'=>2.333,'57'=>2.437,'58'=>2.548,'59'=>2.603,'60'=>2.714,
        '61'=>2.81,'62'=>2.873,'63'=>2.952,'64'=>3.000,'65'=>3.000};

        final map<string, Decimal> ageToRateSmoker = new map<String, Decimal>
    {
        '0'=>1.0,'1'=>1.0,'2'=>1.0,'2'=>1.0,'3'=>1.0,'4'=>1.0,
            '5'=>1.0,'6'=>1.0,'7'=>1.0,'8'=>1.0,
        '9'=>1.0,'10'=>1.0,'11'=>1.0,'12'=>1.0,'13'=>1.0,
            '14'=>1.0,'15'=>1.0,'16'=>1.0,'17'=>1.0,
        '18'=>1.077,'19'=>1.077,'20'=>1.077,'21'=>1.077,
            '22'=>1.077,'23'=>1.077,'24'=>1.077,'25'=>1.08,
        '26'=>1.08,'27'=>1.08,'28'=>1.08,'29'=>1.08,'30'=>1.13,
            '31'=>1.13,'32'=>1.13,'33'=>1.13,
        '34'=>1.13,'35'=>1.132,'36'=>1.132,'37'=>1.132,
            '38'=>1.132,'39'=>1.132,'40'=>1.133,'41'=>1.133,'42'=>1.133,
        '43'=>1.133,'44'=>1.133,'45'=>1.281,'46'=>1.5,
            '47'=>1.281,'48'=>1.281,'49'=>1.281,'50'=>1.397,'51'=>1.397,
        '52'=>1.397,'53'=>1.397,'54'=>1.397,'55'=>1.492,
            '56'=>1.492,'57'=>1.492,'58'=>1.492,'59'=>1.492,'60'=>1.492,
        '61'=>1.492,'62'=>1.492,'63'=>1.492,'64'=>1.492,
            '65'=>1.492,'66'=>1.492,'67'=>1.492,'68'=>1.492,
        '69'=>1.492,'70'=>1.492,'71'=>1.492,'72'=>1.492,
            '73'=>1.492,'74'=>1.492,'75'=>1.492,
            '76'=>1.492,
        '77'=>1.492,'78'=>1.492,'79'=>1.492,'80'=>1.492,'81'=>1.492,'82'=>1.492,'83'=>1.492,'84'=>1.492,
        '85'=>1.492,'86'=>1.492,'87'=>1.492,'88'=>1.492,'89'=>1.492,'90'=>1.492,'91'=>1.492,'92'=>1.492,
        '93'=>1.492,'94'=>1.492,'95'=>1.492,'96'=>1.492,'97'=>1.492,'98'=>1.492,'99'=>1.492,'100'=>1.492,
        '101'=>1.492,'102'=>1.492,'103'=>1.492,'104'=>1.492,'105'=>1.492};
            integer j = 0;
        integer k=0;
            double planAddition = 0;
        for (Subscriber__c sub:subs)
        {          k=k+1;      
            sub.count__c =0;
            sub.Final_Rate__c = 0;
            sub.Ratings_Region_Rate__c=1;





            //populates age and smoker rates with values
            if (ageToRate.containsKey(String.valueOf(sub.Age_on_Effective_Date__c))){sub.Age_Rating__c = ageToRate.get(String.valueOf(sub.Age_on_Effective_Date__c));}
            else{sub.Age_Rating__c = fallbackRate;}
             if (sub.smoker_status__c!=null && sub.smoker_Status__c.equals('yes')&&sub.Plan_Market_Year__c!=null && sub.Plan_Market_Year__c.equals(String.valueOf('2015'))&&sub.RecordTypeId.equals('012i0000000rp5S'))
            {sub.smoker_rate__c = ageToRateSmoker.get(String.valueOf(sub.Age_on_Effective_Date__c));}
            else{sub.smoker_rate__c = smokerFallbackRate;}


            //individual ratings region

            if (sub.Rating_Region__c==null||sub.Plan_Market_Year__c==null){sub.Ratings_Region_Rate__c = 0;} 
            else
            {
        if(sub.Rating_Region__c.contains('1')&&sub.RecordTypeId.equals('012i0000000rp5N')){sub.Ratings_Region_Rate__c = 1.000;}
                else if(sub.Rating_Region__c.contains('2')&&sub.RecordTypeId.equals('012i0000000rp5N')){sub.Ratings_Region_Rate__c = 1.009;}
                else if(sub.Rating_Region__c.contains('3')&&sub.RecordTypeId.equals('012i0000000rp5N')){sub.Ratings_Region_Rate__c = 1.984;}
                else if(sub.Rating_Region__c.contains('4')&&sub.RecordTypeId.equals('012i0000000rp5N')){sub.Ratings_Region_Rate__c = 1.033;}

                //2015 small group
                else if(sub.Rating_Region__c.contains('1')&&sub.Plan_Market_Year__c.equals(String.valueOf('2015'))&&sub.RecordTypeId.equals('012i0000000rp5S')){sub.Ratings_Region_Rate__c = 1.018;}
                else if(sub.Rating_Region__c.contains('2')&&sub.Plan_Market_Year__c.equals(String.valueOf('2015'))&&sub.RecordTypeId.equals('012i0000000rp5S')){sub.Ratings_Region_Rate__c = 0.999;}
                else if(sub.Rating_Region__c.contains('3')&&sub.Plan_Market_Year__c.equals(String.valueOf('2015'))&&sub.RecordTypeId.equals('012i0000000rp5S')){sub.Ratings_Region_Rate__c = 0.967;}
                else if(sub.Rating_Region__c.contains('4')&&sub.Plan_Market_Year__c.equals(String.valueOf('2015'))&&sub.RecordTypeId.equals('012i0000000rp5S')){sub.Ratings_Region_Rate__c = 1.023;}

                //2016 small group
                else if(sub.Rating_Region__c.contains('1')&&sub.Plan_Market_Year__c.equals(String.valueOf('2016'))&&sub.RecordTypeId.equals('012i0000000rp5S')){sub.Ratings_Region_Rate__c = 1.000;}
                else if(sub.Rating_Region__c.contains('2')&&sub.Plan_Market_Year__c.equals(String.valueOf('2016'))&&sub.RecordTypeId.equals('012i0000000rp5S')){sub.Ratings_Region_Rate__c = 1.009;}
                else if(sub.Rating_Region__c.contains('3')&&sub.Plan_Market_Year__c.equals(String.valueOf('2016'))&&sub.RecordTypeId.equals('012i0000000rp5S')){sub.Ratings_Region_Rate__c = 1.984;}
                else if(sub.Rating_Region__c.contains('4')&&sub.Plan_Market_Year__c.equals(String.valueOf('2016'))&&sub.RecordTypeId.equals('012i0000000rp5S')){sub.Ratings_Region_Rate__c = 1.033;}            
                else {sub.Ratings_Region_Rate__c = 0;}
            }
            //else {sub.Ratings_Region_Rate__c = 0;}
            if(sub.Ratings_Region_Rate__c!=null||sub.Base_Rating__c!=null||sub.Plan_Rate__c!=null)
            {sub.Final_Rate__c = sub.Base_Rating__c * sub.Plan_Rate__c * sub.Age_Rating__c *sub.Smoker_Rate__c * sub.Ratings_Region_Rate__c;}
            //adding age and smoker rate functionality
            sub.Family_Rate__c = 0;
            sub.Family_Rate__c = sub.Final_Rate__c;


        //sub.Count__c = 2;
        //list<Subscriber__c> members = [SELECT Attr1__c, COUNT_DISTINCT(Attr__c) FROM Subscriber__c GROUP BY Attr1__c];


        list<Subscriber__c> everyoneElse = [SELECT Age_on_Effective_Date__c, Name, 
                                            count__c, Subscriber_Role__c, Subscriber_ID__c,
                                            Final_Rate__c,Group_ID__c, Family_Rate__c 
                                            from Subscriber__c 
                                            where subscriber_id__c like :sub.Subscriber_ID__c
                                            and Age_on_Effective_Date__c >=22 limit 6];
        list<Subscriber__c> dependents = [SELECT Age_on_Effective_Date__c, Name, 
                                            count__c, Subscriber_Role__c, Subscriber_ID__c,
                                            Final_Rate__c,Group_ID__c, Family_Rate__c
                                            from Subscriber__c 
                                            where subscriber_id__c like :sub.Subscriber_ID__c
                                              and Subscriber_Role__c = 'Dependent'
                                              and Age_on_Effective_Date__c <22 limit 6];      
            for (Subscriber__c unit :everyoneElse){planAddition = unit.Family_Rate__c;
                                                  }             


         for (Subscriber__c dep :dependents)
         {j=j+1;

          system.debug('j = ' + j);
          //system.debug(dep.Subscriber_Role__c+'   '+dep.Subscriber_ID__c);
             if (j>3){sub.count__c =sub.count__c+ dep.Family_Rate__c;
                 system.debug(sub.count__c+''+ dep.Family_Rate__c+'  '+planAddition);

             }
          else{sub.count__c =0;}




          if(j>=7){break;}
         }
            if(sub.count__c!=null&&planAddition!=null)
            {sub.count__c = sub.count__c+planAddition;}
         if(k>=1){break;}
         system.debug('k = ' + k);
        }
    }           
}
```

**Apex Trigger**

```
trigger dependentSearch on Subscriber__c (before insert, before update) {
    dependentSearchClass.dependentSearch(trigger.new);
}
```

Comment: My problem is that I need to get the subscriber Id which is in the loop for the queries to be effective.  I just cant think of another way off of the top of my head.  I originally had half of this in object but i changed it up. I learned all of the data will be static.

Comment: @AndyScott Doesn't matter if the data is static. This code is significantly slower than simply *using* an object. Keep in mind that, unlike some languages, those variables have to be instantiated every time the trigger runs, so more memory used and more CPU time than necessary. You shouldn't underestimate how much slower your system will run because of this.

Comment: I didn't know that. Thanks for the heads up. that would cut out the bulk of the top half of this code

Comment: Also I should have noted in the question is that this only needs to be run one time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, first thing, get rid of that hard-coded Id. You can write a filter method something like the following:

```
static RecordType mySubscriberType
{
    get
    {
        if (mySubscriberType == null)
        { // lazy load pattern
            mySubscriberType = [
                SELECT Id FROM RecordType
                WHERE DeveloperName = 'Some_Type'
            ];
        }
    }
    private set;
}
List<Subscriber__c> isMySubscriberType(List<Subscriber__c> input)
{
    List<Subscriber__c> output = new List<Subscriber__c>();
    for (Subscriber__c record : input)
    {
        if (record.RecordTypeId == mySubscriberType.Id)
        {
            output.add(record);
        }
    }
    return output;
}
```

Now in your trigger, you can instead do:

```
MyClass.search(MyClass.isMySubscriberType(trigger.new));
```

That removes a bunch of `if` clauses you don't really need to check more than once.

---

Now to your root issue. The standard collections based approach should be perfectly adequate here:

```
Set<String> subscriberIds = new Set<String>();
for (Subscriber__c subscriber : subscribers)
    subscriberIds.add(subscriber.Subscriber_Id__c);

Map<String, List<Subscriber__c>> siblings = new Map<String, List<Subscriber__c>>();
for (Subscriber__c sibling : [
    SELECT /*fields*/ FROM Subscriber
    WHERE Subscriber_Id__c IN :subscriberIds
    /*AND other_clauses*/
]){
    if (!siblings.containsKey(sibling.Subscriber_Id__c))
        siblings.put(sibling.Subscriber_Id__c, new List<Subscriber__c>());
    siblings.get(sibling.Subscriber_Id__c).add(sibling);
}
```

You could do a couple such maps, such as `dependentSiblings` and `otherSiblings`. Then within your loop you can just do:

```
List<Subscriber__c> dependents = dependentSiblings.get(sub.Subscriber_ID__c);
```

Answer (score 0):

In this line from your SOQL `where subscriber_id__c like :sub.Subscriber_ID__c` why are you using the `like` keyword?  These two values are the same you could use the `in` keyword.

What you could do is run a for loop to collect all of your `sub.Subscriber_ID__c` in a `Set<Id>`  Use the `Set` to query your `everyoneElse` and `dependents`.  Then use another for loop to put those in a `Map<String, Subscriber__c>` where the Key is the value of the `Subscriber_ID__c`.  Then in a final for loop, loop through your `subs` using the `Subscriber_Id__c` to get the appropriate value from the appropriate `Map<String, Subscriber__c>`